# Location tracking when app is in background in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10

I am new to Windows 10 and currently working on Location based apps. My requirement is to track user locations for a particular time interval and send data to the server every 10 minutes. Can someone suggest whether this is possible in Windows 10 or not? I am not aware of this.

**Update**

I also want to do the above in when the app is in the background also.I tried below code

```
 protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New)
        {
            var extendedSession = new ExtendedExecutionSession();
            extendedSession.Reason = ExtendedExecutionReason.LocationTracking;
            extendedSession.Description = "Location tracking";

            ExtendedExecutionResult result = await extendedSession.RequestExtensionAsync();
            if (result == ExtendedExecutionResult.Allowed)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Background execution approved");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Background execution denied");
            }

            Geolocator locator = new Geolocator();
            locator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 0;
            locator.MovementThreshold = 500;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
            locator.PositionChanged += Locator_PositionChanged;
        }
    }

  private void Locator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(args.Position.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString("0.00000000") + " " + args.Position.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString("0.00000000"));
        if (MCSManager.Instance.userDetails != null && MCSManager.Instance.userDetails.LOC_TRACK_ENABLED.Equals("1") && userSettings.Values.ContainsKey(Constants.USER_ID))
        {
            DatabaseManager dbManager = new DatabaseManager();
            Location_Tracking location_tracking = WebserviceED.StoreLocationData(args.Position.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString(),
                args.Position.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString(), WebserviceED.getTimestamp(), args.Position.Coordinate.Accuracy.ToString());
            var insertSuccessfull = dbManager.insertSingleRecord(location_tracking);
        }
    }
```

in these, I only get location details when the app is in the foreground or minimized. If I kill the app, it doesn't give me location details. Also, please help me how to used this in Background Tasks and how to fire a time trigger to send data to a server even if user kills the app?

Also, can we use more than one Background Tasks? I want to use one for TimeTrigger to send data to a server and another one for Push Notification purpose.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.aspx

Comment: There is a similar case, see [Real time GPS UWP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36196993/real-time-gps-uwp).

Comment: Hi, Please take the advise from others on this page. You will need to understand the basics of Geolocation and background tasks. Lots of reading and learning I'm afraid.

Comment: Edit: Take the advise from Harshad Vekariya on this page. You will need to understand the basics of Geolocation and background tasks. Lots of reading and learning I'm afraid. The code sample you have below sharpgis will not help you.

What you need to do is 100% possible in UWP and be aware that you can only send data to the server when connection is available. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

It totally possible to access to Location of user in windows 10.
It can be access from different source like;

- GPS : within approximately 10 meters
- Wi-Fi : between approximately 30 meters and 500 meters
- Cell towers : between approximately 300 meters and 3,000 meters
- IP address : between approximately 1,000 meters and 5,000 meters

For Technical understanding you can refer following link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.aspx

and for the video from channel , refer

https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-059-UWP-Weather-Accessing-the-GPS-Location

These are good articles to refer.

For Some more technical Detail:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt219698.aspx

and kind of example,

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MapControl

Comment: Update my question. Can you suggest whether it will track location even the app is in background and sent data to server when the app is in background.

Comment: Yes, you need to create background service for that. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-a-background-task-on-a-timer-

Answer (score 1):

Its totally possible. But if user refuse to give location, then you can't.

**UPDATE**

For tracking in background, you need to use `ExtendedExecutionSession`, code sample here: http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2015/03/29/Using-Windows-10s-Extended-Execution

Comment: This is basically what you need: http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2015/03/29/Using-Windows-10s-Extended-Execution

Comment: @thang241099 This shows to track location in background but it doesn't confirm that we can send data to server every 10 minutes. Please suggest

Comment: you can save it to shared setting folder and upload it in extended session or in background task.

Comment: I will be storing all the location in the database and send to the server every 10 minutes by consuming a web service. This will be possible right?

Comment: I tried the sample from the link you provided but it works when the app is in the foreground and when in the background it is available in recent apps(still open but minimized). If I kill the app then it doesn't give location details to me. I checked in Settings and background process is on for my app.

Comment: the background task with timer trigger can only be invoked once in 15 mins. Debug your background task to see if it work

Comment: But you said we can use it every 10 minutes also? I used to sample from http://blog.qmatteoq.com/the-new-background-features-in-windows-10/ which added Extended execution part in NavigatedTo method of the main page.Please can you add sample code if I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> in these, I only get location details when the app is in the foreground or minimized. If I kill the app, it doesn't give me location details.

Extended Execution requires the user to have opened your app and have it in the backstack where they are aware of it running. Here is the tutorial on Extended Execution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution

> Also, please help me how to used this in Background Tasks and how to fire a time trigger to send data to a server even if user kills the app?

Extended Execution Location Tracking cannot be used in a background task. However, you could use a LocationTrigger and record the new location every time the user moves out of a geofenced area. As of the Anniversary Update Location Trigger and Time Trigger can be registered as in-proc or out-of-proc tasks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-an-inproc-background-task

Here is the sample for in-proc background tasks: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundActivation

> Also, can we use more than one Background Tasks? I want to use one for TimeTrigger to send data to a server and another one for Push Notification purpose.

Yes, you can register as many separate kinds of tasks as you need with BackgroundTaskBuilder and they can run inside your application process or as a separate background task process.

Here is the tutorial on using BackgroundTaskBuilder: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task

Here is the sample for out-of-proc background tasks: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTask